# Changing lines in a txt file

Tags: c#

Kinda new to C#

Is there anyway to alter text inside a txt file using c#?

I want to open a text file containing:

```
8881
8882
8883
8884
8885
```

Place them inside an Array, alter the lines to this:

```
'8881',
'8882',
'8883',
'8884',
'8885',
```

And then write out a new txt files with the altered lines.

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt");

//Foreach that lists all lines
System.Console.WriteLine("WriteLines2.txt contains following lines = ");
foreach (string line in lines)
{         
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

How do i procceed to being able to alter each line and write them in a new txt?

Comment: you'll need to iterate over the contents of the files, and modify them.

Comment: `changedLine = "'" + line + "',"` will convert `8881` to `'8881',`

Comment: You are doing this : Open, read all into an array, close. Then work with the array. With large files it may be very slow and even fail because of insufficient memory. Instead open, read line by line, wrting out in between and close. You can test with some millions of lines.

Comment: Off topic, if you are not doing this for learning, why are you converting that into something like that? Smells like a database operation. If its purpose is that, many database backends would simply read the original just fine.

Comment: @CetinBasoz yes im aware that with huge files its better to streamread than load. I am doing it for learning ofc.
It has nothing to do with database. Simply want to learn to manipulate the file. With SSMS it would be very different, yes. And i would not require any help.

Answer (score 7):

You could use following simple LINQ query and `File.WriteAllLines`:

```
var newLines = from line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
               select String.Format("'{0}',", line);
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filePath, newLines);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I missed the select String.Format part completely. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can override the same file with the new lines.

```
String path = @"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt";
String[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
//I'm using System.Linq to change the lines. I'm adding a "'" before and after the original token.
String[] changedLines = lines.Select(x => string.Format("'{0}',", x)).ToArray();

// I'm saving the changes to the file.
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, changedLines);
```

You can also do it without System.Linq

```
string[] path = @"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt";
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);

// change every line
for (int index = 0; index < lines.Length; ++index)
{         
    lines[index] = string.Format("'{0}',", lines[index]);
}

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
```

Comment: `'{0}'` should be `'{0}',`

Comment: Thank you! Helps me out alot!

Answer (score 0):

```
var linesModified = lines.Select (l => string.Format(@"'{0}',",l));
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2_Out.txt", linesModified);
```

EDIT: Efficient version using streaming rather than loading (maybe a large file) the whole file into memory:

```
void Main()
{
  string inFileName = @"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt";
  string outFileName = @"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2_Out.txt";

  using(var r = File.OpenText(inFileName))
  using(var w = File.CreateText(outFileName))
  {
    string line;
    while ( (line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        w.WriteLine(string.Format(@"'{0}',",line));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "File.WriteAllLines" demands array of string instead of enumberable
will show you invalid argument

Comment: Anyway, you reminded me to add an efficient version :)

Comment: My god. I guess i havent had enough coffee today. Your code made alot of sense

Answer (score 0):

you can try this using linq

```
//read the fine and alter it by Select Function 
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").Select(item =>  string.Format("'{0}',",item)).ToArray();
    //write the lines to disk
    File.WriteAllLines("file02.txt",lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
var file = File.ReadLines("path");
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var t in file)
{
   if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t))
        sb.AppendLine("'" + t + "',");
}
File.WriteAllLines("path", new string[] { sb.ToString() });
```